# How to pass all throttled data traffic to an unthrottled port and browse internet at full speed

Tags: internet, udp

There are multiple TCP/UDP based VPN apps which can provide free internet. I'm no expert in this field but according to what I understand is that these apps can work if you are able to browse at least one website without any internet plan. They pass all the normal internet traffic through that one website so that your operator thinks you are still browsing that one free website.
Can someone throw some light on how this process exactly works and can I use it to make my internet work faster because when I exhaust my data limit still some websites work at full speed.

Comment: I don't see how this is possible, this isn't how VPN's work... They REQUIRE an internet connection to make the tunnel from your device to their VPN server, without a valid internet connection you cannot build the VPN tunnel.

Comment: "if you are able to browse at least one website without any internet plan" Many operators allow their official homepage or webportal address to be reached to show ads without having any internet connection. VPN apps use these addresses as host and with appropriate port they can tunnel whole internet traffic thru it. Related info here https://dnstunnel.de

Comment: Yeah, but you are talking about captive portal bypass via DNS remapping or IP routing, completely different... years ago those types of restrictions only stopped you from resolving DNS through public servers, it is completely different now with legitimate routing restrictions in modern WiFi captive portal systems. You are talking about a completely different scenario when you have service to access your carriers website but not the rest of the internet. Try it, open a terminal and see if you can ping 8.8.8.8 or another IP, if you can this might work, but I doubt it will.